# Visible part of Navigation View when collapsed?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How to set visible part of Navigation View when collapsed and the items are also clickable, but when the user drags the drawer full  appears. Im trying to use `layout_margionRight` but it doesn`t work. I want to create Navigation View is like a`NavigationSlidingPanel`. Help please.  Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_height="55dp"

            android:background="@drawable/bg_color_toolbar" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_color2"

    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nd_head"
    android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
   />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```